# Angular ViewChildren QueryList changes on *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, viewchild

Stackblitz: [example](https://angular-wtcgdk.stackblitz.io/)

According the following documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

> You can use ViewChildren to get the QueryList of elements or directives from the view DOM. Any time a child element is added, removed, or moved, the query list will be updated, and the changes observable of the query list will emit a new value.

I understand that to mean I can subscribe to the changes and expect a value to be emitted exactly when an item in the QueryList is, well, "added, removed, or moved".

However, if I have an *ngIf directive in the component that toggles on and off I am receiving a `changes` event when absolutely nothing was "added, removed, or moved".

Browsing through the following article: https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f
I find the following:

> updates ViewChildren query list on the current view component instance

Does that mean the the view children changes fires whenever an item is "added, removed, or moved" OR during a change detection cycle?

I am not understanding something fundamental here.  Is the documentation vague, is there a bug, am I doing something wrong?  Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

All the code is located in the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtcgdk